# Slow downloading of Facebook Place pictures

Tags: facebook-graph-api, download, image

I'd like to download all pictures (in small size) for places I've retrieved via a search with type=place via the Facebook API. It works fine getting the pictures (a la graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture?type=small), but it's darn slow (Android via Wi-Fi or 3G). For a set of 25ish pictures it takes up to 10 seconds. Is the only option to go for caching or is there a way to download the pictures faster, possibly together with the other data in a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most time consuming part of any query is the transit time. If you're making single API calls in a loop of some kind, it's going to slow your application down to a crawl. I'd say you're doing really good if you're making 25 API calls in 10 seconds. Most of the time it takes me about 1 sec/call.

If speed is your prime concern, make a single API call that gets everything at once. FQL or  batch.request allows you to do this.

Comment: OK. I'll try that. First version will be without pictures, so I get the other features field-tested.

Comment: Any experience of how pictures would be returned when using batch requests? They are individual files after all.